# Test Cases Failure on Hackerrank

Tags: c, loops, pattern-matching

For problem statement, I've attached two photos.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/22zyM.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5c8e6.png

My Code :

```
for(i=0;i<300;i++)
{
    x[i]=i;y[i]=i;z[i]=i;
}

//printf("Enter number : "); 
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("%d\n",n);
//for(i=0;i<n;i++)
i=0;
do
{
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
        {
            if(x[i]+y[j]+z[k]==n)
            {
                printf("%d %d %d \n",x[i],y[j],z[k]);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}while(i<n);
```

Now, the output that I'm getting for custom input values is correct for all values. But when I'm trying to check it for the test cases on the website it is showing correctly for only two cases.

Link for problem statement :https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/beautiful-3-set/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&isFullScreen=false

Please help me in solving this issue. Thanks.

Comment: For which cases is it failing. Include that in the question.

Comment: `i` never gets incremented if the condition `x[i]+y[j]+z[k]==n` is not met. Not sure if the input has some behaviour that this never happens!

Comment: Your photos did not appear. It is probably better this way. Images of text have a tendency to produce more scorn than answers and [should not be used for many other good reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4581301).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n, k;

int main() {
scanf("%d", &n);
k = (2 * n) / 3;
printf("%d", k + 1);
printf("\n");
int y = 2 * k - n;
int x = n - 2 * y;
for (int i = 0; i <= y; i++) {
    printf("%d %d %d", i, x + i, n - x - 2 * i);
    printf("\n");
}
for (int i = 0; i < k - y; i++) {
    printf("%d %d %d", y + i + 1, i, n - y - 1 - 2 * i);
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```